# How to call a property of an object with a variable in C# e.g. customer.&fieldName

Tags: c#

In C# is there a way you can call a property of an object with a variable, something like this:

```
string fieldName = "FirstName";
Console.WriteLine(customer.&fieldName);
```

### ANSWER:

Excellent, thanks for the quick answers, this is what I was trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestLinqFieldIndex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            customers.Add(new Customer { ID = 1, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Smith" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { ID = 2, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Douglas" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { ID = 3, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Anders" });

            var customer = (from c in customers
                            where c.ID == 2
                            select c).SingleOrDefault();

            string[] fieldNames = { "FirstName", "LastName" };
            foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value of {0} is {1}.", fieldName, customer.GetPropertyValue(fieldName));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string GetPropertyValue(string fieldName)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Customer).GetProperty(fieldName);
            return prop.GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using reflection.

```
PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Customer).GetProperty ("FirstName");
Console.WriteLine (prop.GetValue (customer, null));
```

It is even possible to retrieve the value of a private property as well.  To do that, you'll have to take a look at the overloaded `GetProperty` method that accepts bindingflags.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that out of the box; you'll have to use the `PropertyInfo` object and reflection:

```
Apple myApple = new Apple("Golden Delicious", Ripeness.Fresh);

// ...

var p = typeof(Apple).GetProperty("Variety");
Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(myApple, null)); // "Golden Delicious"
```

Note that C# 4 will offer support for dynamic property access and other goodness. But I assume you don't want to wait that long. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values of the properties of said object in a dictionary and provide access to that dictionary from outside the class, or use reflection.  Other than that I can't think of a way to do this.

However, pretty much no matter the solution, you'd lose type safety.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

You might find that the correct way to approach this is to use something like the strategy pattern.  That way you encapsulate the logic for using the properties into classes that know which properties they need, then at runtime decide which of those strategy classes to instantiate and pass it your object.

As Frederik says below, you could use reflection, but again the type safety argument comes up, and you may find you get runtime errors you couldn't legislate for at design time.

Comment: I'm trying to respond to the TheDataGrid_CellEditEnding event to save the value of a cell back to the object via linq-to-sql, but I only have the index and the name of the object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674108/how-to-do-get-this-crud-code-to-work-on-wpf-datagrid/674288#674288

Comment: Ahh I see, fair point.  You should add that to your question, though I think the answer is fairly unanimous - use reflection.  I recommend trying to put some unit tests around it if you can though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Reflection API.

The below example illustrates how to retrieve the value of a property that returns a string:

```
public string GetValue(string propertyName, object MyInstance)
{
  Type instanceType = typeof(MyInstance);
  // Set the BindingFlags depending on your property type or simply skip them.
  PropertyInfo pi = instanceType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

  // If this is an indexer property, provide the index as the second parameter,
  // else just supply null.
  return (pi.GetValue(MyInstance, null).ToString());
}
```